# Gitlab login issue via Sourcetree

Tags: authentication, repository, gitlab, token, atlassian-sourcetree

I'd like to reach my repositories from my own Gitlab account via Sourcetree.
When I try to add a new account, I need to login into Gitlab, but the process is always failed.

The message is simple:

> Authentication failed

The username and password are correct, I am 100% sure in it because I've tried them in a private session in Chrome.

I'd someone who can explain to me that why I need to login into my Gitlab account if I choose the "Personal Access Token".
I've already created a new token for Sourcetree, but it never asks me just only my basic login data.

Sourcetree is up to date: 3.0.17.2659

[You can see a printscreen here about the login flow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA8CH.png)